# Um range dentro de outro range

Tags: sql

Eu tenho um problema e estou a procura da melhor maneira de resolver.

Eu tenho valores de Min e Max que vem de um banco de dados: Ex:

```
 id      Min    Max
 1        5     10
 2       20     25
 3       60     90 
 4       91     99
```

Caso for inserir um novo Min e Max ele não deve se sobrepor sobre um range que já foi definido ex: de 11-19 é permitido, de 24-50 não pq isso entraria no range do 20-25.

Alguma ideia de como resolver algo deste gênero?

Comment: Java e javascript? Não é problema resolvido com uma query?

Comment: Poderia reformular sua pergunta?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Ricardo! Por favor [inclua o seu código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/210177/edit) na pergunta para que a comunidade possa te ajudar melhor! Faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor como o site funciona, e veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) como melhorar suas perguntas!

Comment: Olá Ricardo! Queres fazer isso no servidor com `SLQ`? ou no browser? esses novos range vêm de onde?

Answer (score 3):

Vamos dividir seu problema em partes:

1. Evitar inserir um valor caso alguma condição aconteça
2. Identificar existência de interseção em intervalos de números reais

Assim, podemos tratar de maneira independente cada ponto de maneira independente.

## Inserção condicionada

Uma inserção condicionada é um `insert` com uma cláusula condicional; eu já vi `insert-select` sendo usado para esse fim, condicionando a inserção à cláusula `where`, `join` ou coisas similares do `select` ou de uma `CTE`. Retirando essas alternativas, não conheço outro jeito de fazer uma inserção condicionada usando apenas DML. Como você não especificou SGBD, não vou aqui usar nenhuma `trigger` ou `procedure` para essa inserção.

Uma inserção com condicional é semelhante à inserção com valores mas, no lugar de especificar uma tupla com valores a serem inseridos, o retorno de uma consulta será inserido.

Por exemplo, imagine um relatório que depende de uma consulta muito pesada. Para não executar a consulta várias vezes, armazene seu resultado em uma tabela:

```
INSERT INTO relatorio_bacana (mes_inicio, mes_fim, total)
SELECT
    '03' AS mes_inicio,
    '04' AS mes_fim,
    sum(d.vr) AS total
FROM
    dados d
WHERE
    '03' <= d.mes AND
    d.mes < '04'
```

De grosso modo, isso é uma inserção com seleção. Note que foi colocada uma condicional na seleção: a coluna `mes precisa estar entre os meses de início e de fim. Note que é possível diminuir a verbosidade de termos constantes inseridos: não precisamos escrever duas vezes o mês de início, nem tampouco duas vezes o mês de fim; podemos escrever cada um apenas uma vez, usando uma CTE.

```
WITH q AS (
    SELECT
        '03' AS mes_inicio,
        '04' AS mes_fim
)
INSERT INTO relatorio_bacana (mes_inicio, mes_fim, total)
SELECT
    q.mes_inicio AS mes_inicio,
    q.mes_fim AS mes_fim,
    sum(d.vr) AS total
FROM
    dados d, q
WHERE
    q.mes_inicio <= d.mes AND
    d.mes < q.mes_fim
```

## Detecção de interseção entre intervalos

Existem 7 relações possível entre dois intervalos:

1. Idênticos:

   ```
   <--->
   <--->
   ```
2. O primeiro contém o segundo de maneira própria:

   ```
   <----------->
        <----->
   ```
3. O primeiro está contido no segundo de maneira própria:

   ```
         <--->
   <---------->
   ```
4. Interseção no começo do primeiro:

   ```
         <----->
   <------->
   ```
5. Interseção no final do primeiro:

   ```
   <------>
         <------->
   ```
6. Sem interseção, estritamente menor:

   ```
    <--->
                  <----->
   ```
7. Sem interseção, estritamente maior:

   ```
                     <--->
   <--->
   ```

Como estamos trabalhando com intervalos fechados (foi esse o meu entendimento da pergunta), basta apenas que uma das extremidades coincida para que haja caso de pertinência (menor com menor/maior com maior) ou interseção parcial (menor com maior/maior com menor). Caso se misturasse a abertura das extremidades, aí precisaria de maior cuidado.

Seja `m` o valor menor do intervalo e `M` o valor maior do intervalo. Seja `m1` e `M1` relativos ao primeiro intervalo, e analogamente `m2` e `M2` para o segundo.

Se `m1` está em `(m2,M2)` temos então um caso de pertinência própria (3) ou de interseção no começo do intervalo (4). Como não nos interessa saber qual o tipo de relação há entre os dois intervalos, isso basta.

Se `m2` está em `(m1,M1)` temos então um caso de pertinência própria (2) ou interseção no final do intervalo (5).

A consideração com intervalos fechados garante os casos extremos de interseções e de igualdade dos intervalos. Portanto, temos que, para haver alguma forma de interseção (casos 1 ao 5 das 7 relações possíveis), a seguinte relação precisa ser satisfeita:

```
/* m1 dentro de [m2,M2] para casos 1,3,4 */
(m2 <= m1 E m1 <= M2)

    OU

/* m2 dentro de [m1,M1] para casos 1,2,5 */
(m1 <= m2 E m2 <= M1)
```

Em sql, caso a tabela seja chamada de tabela:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t2.id
FROM
    tabela t1,
    tabela t2
WHERE
    (t2.min <= t1.min AND t1.min <= t2.max)
         OR
    (t1.min <= t2.min AND t2.min <= t1.max)
```

Assim, para cada interseção existente na tabela `tabela`, serão impressos os ids das linhas que geraram essa interseção.

## Juntando tudo

Queremos inserir uma nova linha apenas se ela não tiver interseção com outra previamente existente (considerando o id auto gerado):

```
WITH novos_dados AS (
    SELECT
        11 AS min,
        19 AS max
)
INSERT INTO tabela (min, max)
SELECT
     n.min,
     n.max
 FROM
     novos_dados n
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT
          1
      FROM
           tabela t
      WHERE
          (t.min <= n.min AND n.min <= t.max)
               OR
          (n.min <= t.min AND t.min <= n.max)
 )
```